# Вывести в файл или print первые две строки из вывода ifconfig

Tags: python-3.x

Есть небольшой скрипт, который работает, конектится к устройству в локальной сети и применяет настройки.

```
import paramiko
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print (now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='192.168.1.1', username='admin', password='admin')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ifconfig')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
print(data)

filename = open('bad.txt', 'wb')
filename.write(data)
```

Не могу никак добиться, что бы из вывода ifconfig, который записывается в data.
Считывать например первые 2-3 строки.... ?

Comment: А какие попытки уже были? Вон вижу ``print(data)``, значит все содержание уже выводится. Чем не устраивает?

Comment: @Эникейщик
Принт выводит всё, хочется только первую строку, что бы её потом аккуратно записать в файл, просто таких устройств будет около 20-30 и сохранять для каждого весь вывод ifconfig не очень =) Собираюсь просто вытащить мак адреса каждого устройства

Comment: Если data - одна длинная строка, то нужно взять текст до 2-3го символа переноса строки (``\n``).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как-то так:

```
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()

# Разбиваем вывод построчно. 
# Очень полезно ещё тем, что иногда paramico возвращает строки, разделенные \r\n\n
data.splitlines()

print(data[0:2]) # Выводим первые две строки

filename = open('bad.txt', 'wb')
filename.write(data[0:2])
```